# Issues while Upgrading Jsf1.0 to Jsf2.0

Tags: jsf-2

While upgrading application to Jsf2.0 created in Spring3 and Jsf1.0 (myfaces), i am facing some issues mentioned below.

I have done following steps to upgrade the application.

From IntelliJ IDEA:

```
* Open project settings/Monitor/Dependencies
*  Removed facelet*jar, el*.jars, myfaces* jars from project 
*  Added jsf2.0.x ri mojarra jars and tomahawk1.1.9.jar  
*  Open project settings/monitor/web settings
*  Under "modules and libs to package": remove el-.jars,facelet-jar and myfaces jars
*  Added jsf2.0.x ri mojarra jars and tomahawk1.1.9.jar  
*  Removed erroneous class usages from our classes Lists.java and RegExValidator.java. In Lists.java, replace import with org.apache.commons.lang.LocaleUtils. In RegExValidator, replace import with "org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.util.MessageUtils".
```

Edit Web.xml:

```
*  facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS -> javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS
*  facelets.LIBRARIES -> javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES
* Change Faces Servlet to <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
* Change header to:

  <web-app version="2.5"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Edit faces-config.xml:

```
*  Add header:
```

```
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"

          version="2.0">

*  Remove line "<view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>"
```

After doing all the steps mentioned above getting the following error:

> A literal value was specified for attribute actionListener that is defined as a deferred method with a return type of void. JSP.2.3.4 does not permit literal values in this case

Actually Jsf2.0 el expressions #{myBean.property} are not getting resolved thats why its showing the above error.

Can anybody guide me, what is missing, so that i can successfully migrate application to Jsf2.0

Thanks in Advance,
Dhillon

Comment: Does your faces-config have a reference to an EL resolver ?

Answer (score 0):

> A literal value was specified for attribute actionListener that is defined as a deferred method with a return type of void. JSP.2.3.4 does not permit literal values in this case

This EL validation error means that you've somewhere a

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="somestring" />
```

instead of

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{someBean.actionListener}" />
```

or

```
<h:commandButton action="somestring" />
```

*(instead of `h:commandButton` you can also read any `UICommand` component like  `h:commandLink`)*

Just locate/lookup the culprit in the code and fix it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `web-app version="3.0"` to latest. Previously web-app version is 2.5 at that time I got error, after upgrade to 3.0 issue resolved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <display-name></display-name> 
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```