# JSF 2.3.3 jar - Error message JSP.2.3.4 does not permit literal values in this case

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am updating myfaces jar from 1.1.5 to 2.3.3 (myfaces-impl-2.3.3 and myfaces-api-2.3.3)and the old jsp page is throwing below error. Does this not work in the new myfaces 2.3.3 version? Is there any other jar that needs to be updated? What is the change needed to get this resolved?

> A literal value was specified for attribute actionListener that is
>   defined as a deferred method with a return type of void. JSP.2.3.4
>   does not permit literal values in this case

```
  <h:commandLink  actionListener="#{MyBean.testmethod}" action="testmethod" >
                    <h:outputText value="exit" />
   </h:commandLink> 

class MyBean{

    public void testmethod(ActionEvent ae){
        System.out.println("calling test method");
    }   

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSP & EL conflict with JSF 1.x actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858017/jsp-el-conflict-with-jsf-1-x-actionlistener)

Comment: Likely also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311412/issues-while-upgrading-jsf1-0-to-jsf2-0

Comment: Below did not help me. I still get the same error.                                          <web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

Comment: I updated myfaces jar from 1.1.5 to 2.3.3. Is there any other jar I have to update which is causing the issue?